# Permission denied when using Make in GCC

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, makefile

I've been reading An Introduction to GCC - for the GNU compilers gcc and g++

There's some example where you have hello world program divided in 3 different files (main.c, hello_fn.c, hello.h). In this example it shows the use of makefile.

```
CC=gcc 
CFLAGS=-Wall
main: main.o hello_fn.o

clean:
    rm -f main main.o hello_fn.o
```

The point he makes is when you change only one file, for example main.c, by using make you will need to only compile the file you've changed when making a new executable file.

I make an executable file successfully but when I make a simple change in main.c for it to print "Hello everyone!" instead "Hello world!" it throws Permission denied error. Also you can't run that executable file anymore, it says "Access is denied."

Now what's interesting is it throws the error for about 10 minutes or so, but after ~10 minutes it compiles successfully! You can see it here:

```
C:\Users\Neven\Documents\C\GCC knjiga\New Hello>main
Hello, world!

C:\Users\Neven\Documents\C\GCC knjiga\New Hello>make
gcc  -Wall   -c -o main.o main.c
gcc    main.o hello_fn.o   -o main
c:/rtools/gcc-4.6.3/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.6.3/../../../../i686-w64-m
ingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file main.exe: Permission denied
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [main] Error 1

C:\Users\Neven\Documents\C\GCC knjiga\New Hello>main
Access is denied.
```

My question is, why is there a time interval where you can't execute make?

Comment: Please don't post (links to) images of text; post the text directly.

Answer (score 3):

Application does not end. That's why you don't have permission to write to that process. Probably after those 10 minutes, you break some loop or made it sleep for 600 seconds after typing "Hello World".

Comment: Here is the code

main.c http://pastebin.com/EXh2Kkhz

hello_fn.c http://pastebin.com/eyBkFeee

header.h http://pastebin.com/HYHWqaMW

How do I make it end?

Comment: Check in task manager if there is process called `main.exe` when getting `Access is denied` message.

Comment: I checked and there isn't.

Comment: But you're checking list of all users? You forgot to mention that you run cmd.exe as administrator, didn't you?

Comment: Yes, I am checking list of all users. I didn't pay attention to how I ran cmd.exe. I open start, search for cmd and press ENTER. I tried running it as an administrator and nothing changes.